# Cartoon series with a group of adventurers fighting huge worms in one episode

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It was a series, but I only remember one episode: they were fighting a number of (maybe 3?) giant worms which become alive if someone stole a relic inside them. I still remember the closing scene: Kids playing a ball game next to a hill with an American flag on it, but actually the hill is the "lost" worm which is still dormant.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the adventurers? How old were they? What did they look like? What did they wear? Did they use special weapons or tools or have super powers? And was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated?

Comment: It was taking place in a jungle, this episod. A group of men, modern guns. There was ongoing theme about a lost father (not sure, but a man who they thought died but not). I watched it around 2005-2010 if it helps.

Comment: *Chris Colorado* hits the "Post-apocalyptic" with a missing father IIRC. But I haven't found any worm or ball game references.